sum hight cost from same id
hello i need help i was try but give up
i have table shipping



id
order_id
supplier_id
shipping_cost




1
37575000001
2
20000


2
37575000001
2
40000


3
37575000001
10
20000


4
37575000001
10
30000



i want to calculate height shipping_cost with same supplier_id
from the table is 40000 and 30000 total_shipping_cost is 70000
i was try with query
<?php
$query = "SELECT shipping_cost FROM shipping where order_id='37575000001' group by supplier_id order by shipping_cost desc";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{   
$shipping_cost=$row['shipping_cost'];    
    $total_shipping_cost=$total_shipping_cost+$shipping_cost; 
} 

echo $total_shipping_cost;
?>

but the result is 40000
please help

SELECT DISTINCT SUM(MAX(shipping_cost)) OVER () AS total_shipping_cost
FROM shipping
GROUP BY supplier_id;


Use
$query = "SELECT SUM(`max_shipping_cost`) AS `total_shipping_cost` FROM (SELECT MAX(`shipping_cost`) AS `max_shipping_cost` FROM `shipping` where `order_id`='37575000001' GROUP BY `supplier_id`) temp";

If you want to use loop, Use this query
$query = "SELECT MAX(`shipping_cost`) AS `shipping_cost` FROM `shipping` where `order_id`='37575000001' GROUP BY `supplier_id`";

Also recommend to initialize  $total_shipping_cost before while loop.
